# How to look up for a suitable EDT in the AOT of Microsoft Dynamic AX?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

The stories were like this:

I wrote a class in the AOT and want to declare a variable that stores the number of days between to given dates. I first used the `int` primitive type. Then, I wonder if there is a suitable EDT in AOT. With much *luck* I typed "`NumberOfD`ays" and then the EDT `NumberOfDays` appeared at the first entry in the list of code autocompletion.

Sometimes I do not have that much luck. I wonder if there is a directory for the EDTs in AOT. I do not want to study the list of EDTs from the first entry of the list through the last one.

I have tried to google, and I could find instructions on how to create an EDT, and guidelines that tell me it is a better practice (or the *best practice*) to use EDTs than to use primitive types, BUT I could not find a directory that directs me from the need of an EDT to the destination: an already existing EDT out there that best suits the need. "Oh! The EDT! Where are you?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is no directory of extended data types (EDTs) other than the application object tree (AOT) that makes it easier to find an EDT that you are looking for.

I would say finding EDTs comes down to experience, smart guessing, knowing some tricks and (if nothing else helps) brute force searching the AOT.

**Experience**

Obviously the more you have seen of AX, the more likely you are to know if there is already an EDT or not. Also in my experience looking for general EDTs like your example is more the exception than the norm. Usually you are in a specific business area (like sales orders) and by looking at the tables of that area you can get a good idea what EDTs are available.

**Smart guessing**

Probably what you consider luck in your question, but realistically, there are not that many names that make sense for an EDT. So trying a few different likely names for an EDT you are looking for is imho a valid search strategy.

**Tricks**

Well, more like one trick, the combination of labels and cross references. If you can't find an EDT, try to find a label that the EDT would use. Then check the cross references of that label if it is used by EDTs.

**Brute force search**

Be aware that the search function of the AOT has some nice advanced features and that searching (at least in the EDT node) does not take that long, e.g. searching for "days" took me about 30 seconds and returned 153 results. Still a lot to go through, but much less than going through all 17k EDTs.

**Make your own**

If after all that you still can't find a good existing EDT, it is ok to create your own. Maybe you find out later that there would have been a good existing EDT, but honestly, a redundant EDT is not the end of the world. Don't make it a habit, but also don't fret too much over it.